# Publishing a TypeScript library with Bower

Tags: javascript, typescript, bower, tsd

How to properly build and package a TypeScript library so that it can be used from both JavaScript and TypeScript code easily using Bower and TSD?

Answer (score 2):

Compile your TypeScript sources to both JavaScript and TypeScript Declaration files in your build script:

`tsc <source> <dependencyDeclarations> --out <targetJavaScript> --declaration`

Where `<dependencyDeclarations>` are the `.d.ts` files of your dependencies, conveniently `typings/tsd.d.ts` if you use TSD.

So this command will generate a `.js` and a `.d.ts` file in the same folder with the same name. Let's call the latter `<targetDeclaration>`. Specify both in your `bower.json`:

```
{
  "main": "<targetJavaScript>",
  "typescript": {
    "definition": "<targetDeclaration>"
  }
}
```

(You can also ignore every other files.) Then publish your package using Bower as usual.

To use the library, run:

```
bower install <library> --save
tsd link
```

TSD 0.6 will detect and include the specified `<targetDeclaration>`.

Comment: Plus one. One more tip: look at https://github.com/TypeStrong/dts-bundleneeded to generate correct `.d.ts` files if you use `external modules`

Comment: What about other declarations that your library is using? like jQuery.